# Moq Linq-to-SQL readonly property

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, linq-to-sql, moq

I have a table `aspnet_User` in my model(dbml file) where I have a property `UserName` which is ReadOnly. I thought I could do this.

```
var mockAsp_NetUser = new Mock<aspnet_User>();
mockAsp_NetUser.SetupGet(au => au.UserName).Returns("JohnDoe");
```

But then I get an exception: Invalid setup on a non-overridable member.

An easy solution would be to set the ReadOnly property for `UserName` to false in the model designer. But this might be a hack. Is there a more "correct" way?

Answer (score 1):

You can't mock what is not either virtual or abstract.

If you are trying to unit test your code, a better approach would be to define an IUser class and let your code work against that interface.

Comment: I have read that it is "almost impossible" to mock linq tables in datacontext. TypeMock Isolator is able to this, but not Moq.

Comment: That is right, TypeMock is a completely different beast than all the other dynamic mocks - for good and evil...

Answer (score 1):

Just an addition to Marks answer:

In the DBML you can set that the property should have **"Instance Modifier" = "virtual"**. By default its set to (None).

For your example that means: In the DBML Designer, select the Member "UserName" and in the Properties you will find "Instance Modifier".

Once set to virtual your code will work.